# How to get container name from container ID using python docker module

Tags: python, docker, python-docker

I would like to get the container name by passing container id. I have tried below for getting that but unfortunately it didn't worked for me.

```
 import docker
 def get_container_details(self,container=123456789992):
     self.client = docker.from_env()
     print(self.client.containers.get(container))
```

May I know what is missing and how to get the container name from container ID

Answer (score 3):

You were just a step away. Look at the snippet below,

```
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> client.containers.list()
[<Container: 1c9276a9ca>]
>>> client.containers.get('1c9276a9ca').name
u'unruffled_mahavira'
```

Answer (score 0):

The list method of containers gives the Id of the container only. To get the corresponding name, you have to use name attribute, like below --

```
client = docker.from_env()

def get_all_container_list():
    containers = client.containers.list()
    for i in containers:
        print(i.name, i)
```

More to follow at [official documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#)